# Strip domain name from full domain

Tags: php

I'm looking for a quick way of getting parts of a domain name:

**Example:** http://www.mydomain.com/something/hello.html

I need to get the "mydomain.com" part and nothing else.

But, the url may change sometime, for example:

http://mydomain.com/something/hello.html

http://www.mydomain.com/hello.html

http://mydomain.com

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

string parse to first instance of '.com' and strip the rest of the domain name from string

Comment: Not the best way of doing this - PHP has built in methods (`parse_url`) that are more efficient and are the *correct* way of achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `parse_url` to get information about an URL.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
/path
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url). Pass it a url and it returns an associative array with values for:

- scheme
- host
- port
- user
- pass
- path
- query
- fragment